# Why is this IsNum function wrong?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Function IsNum(textBox As TextBox, name As String) As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(textBox) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show(name & " is not a number.", "Entry Error")
        textBox.Select()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

After writing this function, apparently I wrote it in a way if I make a number it doesn't think that it's a number. Is there a better way to write it so it's not so confusing and incorrect?

Comment: `IsNumeric(textBox.Text)` it uses the Text property - not the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the text inside textbox. Not textbox itself.

Do this instead..

```
 If IsNumeric(textBox.Text) = False Then
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something that my eye couldn't catch. Had too much code written. Thanks.

Comment: There is also a limit to the size of a number when using isNumeric I can't remember exact the size but once you hit that limit isNumeric is always false.

Answer (score 3):

Since you using .NET Framework (based on the tag `vb.net`) - I suggest to use strongtyped text parsing to the number

I assume you know what kind of number type you are expecting (`Int32`, `Decimal`, `Double` etc.)

Use `TryParse` method [Int32.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Private Function IsNum(textBox As TextBox, name As String) As Boolean
    Dim temp As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(textBox.Text, temp) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show(name & " is not a number.", "Entry Error")
        textBox.Select()
        Return False
    End If
    'If values is valid you can use valid Integer for your purposes
    Me.SomeInteger = temp
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this. First would be to use a NumericUpDown control or a custom TextBox that only accepts numeric input as shown next which also takes into consideration data pasted from the windows clipboard. Add the class to your project, build, at the top of the IDE toolbox click on the custom text box to add to your form and simply use it.

```
Public Class numericTextbox
    Inherits TextBox

    Const WM_PASTE As Integer = &H302

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Dim Value As String = Me.Text
        Value = Value.Remove(Me.SelectionStart, Me.SelectionLength)
        Value = Value.Insert(Me.SelectionStart, e.KeyChar)
        e.Handled = CBool(Value.LastIndexOf("-") > 0) _
           Or Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse _
           Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse _
           (e.KeyChar = "."c And Not Me.Text.Contains(".") Or _
           e.KeyChar = "."c And _
           Me.SelectedText.Contains(".")) OrElse (e.KeyChar = "-"c And Me.SelectionStart = 0))
        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_PASTE Then
            Dim Value As String = Me.Text
            Value = Value.Remove(Me.SelectionStart, Me.SelectionLength)
            Value = Value.Insert(Me.SelectionStart, Clipboard.GetText)
            Dim result As Decimal = 0
            If Not Decimal.TryParse(Value, result) Then
                Return
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Another idea dependent on the targeted framework 3.5 and up is to use extension methods.

```
Public Module LanguageExtensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Check if Text property of a TextBox is numeric
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNumeric(ByVal sender As TextBox) As Boolean
        Return Integer.TryParse(sender.Text, Nothing) OrElse Double.TryParse(sender.Text, Nothing)
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Check if Text Property of a TextBox is a decimal with formatting or not
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNumericWithCurrency(ByVal sender As TextBox) As Boolean
        Return Decimal.TryParse(sender.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, Nothing)
    End Function

End Module
```

Example for extension methods

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.IsNumericWithCurrency Then
            MessageBox.Show("Yes")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

If none of these suit your needs I would go with Fabio's suggestion.